# Adding specific data for each section in UITableView - Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a Table view with data compiled from a Dictionary array where the keys are the section headers:

```
var data: Dictionary<String,[String]> = [
    "Breakfast": ["Oatmeal","Orange Juice"],
    "lunch": ["Steak","Mashed Potatoes","Mixed Veg"],
    "Dinner": ["Chicken","Rice"],
    "Snack": ["Nuts","Apple"]

]
var breakfastCalories = [100,200,300]
var lunchCalories = [300,400,500]
var DinnerCalories = [600,700,800]
var breakfast = 0
```

Below is the code for populating the Table View

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for value in breakfastCalories as NSArray as! [Int]{

    breakfast = breakfast + value

    }

}


func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return data.count
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    let sectionString = Array(data.keys)[section]

    return data[sectionString]!.count
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let sectionString = Array(data.keys)[section]
    return sectionString
}


 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let sectionString = Array(data.keys)[indexPath.section]


    cell.caloriesLabel.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.caloriesLabel.text = String(breakfastCalories[indexPath.row])
    cell.foodLabel.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.foodLabel.text = data[sectionString]![indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
//    self.myTableView.tableFooterView = footerView;


    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(footerView.frame.origin.x - 15, footerView.frame.origin.y, footerView.frame.size.width, 20))
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right

    label.text = "Total Calories: \(breakfast) "

    footerView.addSubview(label)

    return footerView
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) ->  CGFloat {

    return 20.0
}
```

My question is, how can I add the calories array for each section? so for breakfast, it will contain the calories from the breakfastCalories array, lunch section for the lunchCalories array etc.

I may be overthinking this but I can't get my head around this problem

Thanks

[image: This is my table view.]
 On the right the values are grabbed from the breakfastCalories however as mentioned each section contain the calories from the breakfastCalories array, lunch section for the lunchCalories array etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could structure your `calories` similar to your `data` property, with similar keys:

```
var calories: Dictionary<String,[Int]> = [
"Breakfast": [100,200,300],
"lunch": [300,400,500],
"Dinner": [600,700,800]
]
```

That way you can pull out the right calories depending on what section you are showing and add them up to create a total for you label to show: (Add this where you create your footerView and just above where you set your label.text)

```
let dataKeysArray = Array(data.keys)[section]
let sectionString = dataKeysArray[section]
let mealCalories = calories[sectionString]

var totalCalories: Int = 0
for calories in mealCalories {
    totalCalories += calories
}

label.text = "Total Calories: \(totalCalories) "
```

Comment: this solution does make sense, however I am getting a the unexpectedly found nil error on mealCalories

Comment: Nevermind, just a silly mistake. I did not add calories for my snacks so it is set to nil. Thank you for your swift solution

Comment: **@JoeBenton** I have a similar question that adds the total of the cells into the footer, do you think you could help me with it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039423/how-to-get-total-in-footer-cell-of-cells-in-sections