# How to get total in footer cell of cells in sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, footer, sections

Currently Im able to get cells to add up their total in the sections Footer Cell. But it calculates the total for every cell no matter what section its in, inside the all the sections footer.

I still can't get it to add up the different prices(Price1 - 3) for the cells that have a different prices selected passed into it the Section

code im using to add up total in the CartFooter for the Cells in the sections `cartFooter.cartTotal.text = "\(String(cart.map{$0.cartItems.price1}.reduce(0.0, +)))"`

PREVIOUSLY:

im trying to get the Cells in each section to add up their total in **footer cell** for each section that they're in.

The data in the CartVC is populated from another a VC(HomeVC). Which is why there is 3 different price options in the **CartCell** for when the data populates the cells.

Just kind of stuck on how I would be able to get the total in the **footer** for the cells in the section

[Adding specific data for each section in UITableView - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36387247/adding-specific-data-for-each-section-in-uitableview-swift)

Thanks in advance, Your help is much appreciated

[image]

```
extension CartViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return brands
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let brand = brands[section]
        return groupedCartItems[brand]!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cartCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartCell") as! CartCell

        let brand = brands[indexPath.section]
        let cartItemsToDisplay = groupedCartItems[brand]![indexPath.row]
        cartCell.configure(withCartItems: cartItemsToDisplay.cartItems)

        return cartCell
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let cartHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CartHeader") as! CartHeader

        let headerTitle = brands[section]
        cartHeader.brandName.text = "Brand: \(headerTitle)"

    return cartHeader
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
         let cartFooter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FooterCell") as! FooterCell
        let sectionTotal = cart[section].getSectionTotal()

        let calculate = String(cart.map{$0.cartItems.price1}.reduce(0.0, +))
        cartFooter.cartTotal.text = "$\(calculate)"

        return cartFooter
    }

}
```

**Update:** these are the results that I am getting using this in the CartFooter

```
let calculate = String(cart.map{$0.cart.price1}.reduce(0.0, +))
cartFooter.cartTotal.text = "$\(calculate)"
```

which calculates the **overall total** (OT) for all the sections and places the OT in all all Footer Cells(as seen below ▼) when im trying to get the total for each section in their footers (as seen in image above ▲ on the right side)

[image]

**Update2:**

this what ive added in my `cellForRowAt` to get the totals to add up in the section footer. it adds up the data for the cells but it doesn't give an accurate total in the footer

```
    var totalSum: Float = 0

    for eachProduct in cartItems{
        productPricesArray.append(eachProduct.cartItem.price1)
        productPricesArray.append(eachProduct.cartItem.price2)
        productPricesArray.append(eachProduct.cartItem.price3)
        totalSum = productPricesArray.reduce(0, +)

        cartFooter.cartTotal.text = String(totalSum)
    }
```

Comment: can you share Items code please?

Comment: just added the items class @AndresGomez

Comment: Can you re-phrase your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Evelyn Try calculation directly in footer. Try below code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cartFooter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FooterCell") as! FooterCell
    let brand = brands[indexPath.section]
    let arrAllItems = groupedCartItems[brand]!
    var total: Float = 0
    for item in arrAllItems {
        if item.selectedOption == 1 {
             total = total + Float(item.price1)
        } else item cartItems.selectedOption == 2 {
             total = total + Float(item.price2)
        } else if item.selectedOption == 3 {
             total = total + Float(item.price3)
        }
    }
    cartFooter.cartTotal.text = "$\(total)"
    return cartFooter
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of code, and I'm not too sure where your coding error lies. With that said:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
     let cartFooter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FooterCell") as! FooterCell
    let sectionTotal = cart[section].getSectionTotal()

    let calculate = String(cart.map{$0.cart.price1}.reduce(0.0, +))
    cartFooter.cartTotal.text = "$\(calculate)"

    return cartFooter
}
```

Your code seems to say  `let sectionTotal = cart[section].getSectionTotal()` is the total you are looking for (i.e. the total within a section), while you are displaying the OT in a section, by summing up `String(cart.map{$0.cart.price1}.reduce(0.0, +))`.

In other words, if `cartFooter` is the container that will display the total within a section, one should read `cartFooter.cartTotal.text = "$\(sectionTotal)"` instead, no?

If that's not the answer, I suggest that you set a breakpoint each time  the footerView is instantiated, and figure out why it output what it outputs (i.e. the OT, instead of the section total).

Comment: Yes that "In other words, if cartFooter is the container that will display the total within a section, one should read cartFooter.cartTotal.text = "$\(sectionTotal)" instead, no?" would be the best way to make it work but so far it has not been been successful no matter what I do

Comment: what happens if you replace `cartFooter.cartTotal.text = "$\(calculate)"` by `cartFooter.cartTotal.text = "$\(sectionTotal)"` ?

Comment: Ok, I think I'm slowly getting the issue... Your problem is that the price selection (1-3) doesn't seem to reflect on the total price in each section correct?

Comment: when I use ```calculate``` it shows the overall total as seen in the second image, when I use ```sectionTotal```  the results are all 0 as seen in the first image on the left.  When you asked **Your problem is that the price selection (1-3) doesn't seem to reflect on the total price in each section correct?**  that's exactly what Im trying to do

Comment: Oh, boy... @Evelyn, your problem isn't a display issue, that part works fine. Your problem is a model issue, and relates to the way it does internal calculations. There's way too much information in your question, all the part relating to the TableView has no relationship whatsoever with the issue you describe. Very, Very confusing.... For my info, the right side of the top first image has the correct total BUT will not feature the correct prices (1-3), am i correct? If so, then your issue lies in `getSectionTotal()`; so: 1/set a break point in there 2/run & debug, i suspect the price....

Comment: ... selection isn't passed, so the code always run the same option. Also, your naming is confusing: the global cart is a collection of Cart instances, each Cart contains a 'cart' attribute, which is a collection of items??... that's a recipe for disasters, because methods will be tied to class names that have different roles, but the same identifiers.. You should redesign your Model code, name each class with a unique name, adequately separate them according to their responsibility, and create all needed accessors, in a way that will help you fill your tableView...

Comment: that is for example globalCart.total(), globalCart.confirm(), globalCart.checkout(), globalCart.ship.get/set(), globalCart.cancel(product indexPath:IndexPath), globalCart.get(basket indexPath:IndexPath) & set(...), globalCart.total(indexPath:IndexPath) etc... along with all the KVO observers so that when a section is modified, your model is updated, and when the model is updated (outside the view), it notifies the TableView. Take a look at https://github.com/Dassine/ShoppingCart. Careful, there are plenty of other example that are NOT to be implemented. Good luck.

Comment: finally, if you are really determined to learn as your profile motto stays, you should take a look at https://www.udemy.com/course/pirate-bay-ios-swift-3-development-complete/ (I have no idea if it's good or not), or equivalent stuff. Store front development is tedious and requires a lot of rigour. It's a f*cking pain in the *ss, but thankfully, all the OOP needed to do it already exists somewhere, so don't reinvent the wheel :p, and rework existing code to your need. If you don't re-use (not copy) someone else's code for this, be sure that you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to correct calculate total price in each section you need filter items for every section. now i think you sum all of your section.
For correct section you need yous snipper from your cellForRow method:

```
let brand = brands[indexPath.section]
        let cartItemsToDisplay = groupedCartItems[brand]![indexPath.row]
        cartCell.configure(withCartItems: cartItemsToDisplay.cart)
```

inside this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
         let cartFooter = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FooterCell") as! FooterCell
        let sectionTotal = cart[section].getSectionTotal()
        let brand = brands[section]
        let catrItemsToDisplay = // now you need to get associated items with this brand (cart)
    // I think it is can looks like this  =  cartItemsToDisplay[brand]
        let calculate = String(cartItemsToDisplay.cart.reduce(0.0, +))
        cartFooter.cartTotal.text = "$\(calculate)"

        return cartFooter
    }
```

Comment: im getting an error on ```let calculate = String(cartItemsToDisplay.cart.reduce(0.0, +))``` saying ***Value of type '[Cart]?' has no member 'cart'*** and I did this to let ```cartItemsToDisplay = groupedCartItems[brand]``` in the viewForFooterInSection. How would I get the code to calculate the total for the cells in the section, ill update my code in few moment to show how things are operating right now

Comment: Remove cart before reduce

Answer (score 0):

**Modify your Model structure and the way values set to through TableViewDelegate. Giving a short hint. Please see if it helps:**

```
class Cart {
   var brandWiseProducts: [BrandWiseProductDetails]!

   init() {
       brandWiseProducts = [BrandWiseProductDetails]()
   }

   initWIthProducts(productList : [BrandWiseProductDetails]) {
       self.brandWiseProducts = productList 
   }    
}



class BrandWiseProductDetails {
      var brandName: String!
      var selectedItems: [Items] 
      var totalAmount: Double or anything
}

class SelectedItem {
     var image
     var name
     var price
}


  Sections:

  Cart.brandWiseProducts.count

  SectionTitle:

  Cart.brandWiseProducts[indexPath.section].brandName

  Rows in section

  Cart.brandWiseProduct[indexPath.section].selectedItem[IndexPath.row]

  Footer:

  Cart.brandWiseProduct.totalAmount
```